# How to get crypto-mining malware samples?

Tags: malware, virus

I am trying to get my hands on some crypto-mining malware samples for my academic research and have tried to access VT and Virusign but both required registration I have emailed them asking for access and I am still waiting.

But for now my question is, is there a website where I can download a package of crypto-mining malware samples? I need it to start the analysis and produce JSON reports.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking where to find resources are off-topic as the list of answers will constantly change

Comment: I did see the post that you suggested but was trying to get something more specific, thanks anyways.